# approximations in lp spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

If $f$ is a bounded measurable function, then, on every ball, the functions $f*\rho_{\epsilon}$ converge to $f$ in the mean and in measure.

This corollary is from V.I.Bogachev, page 253 volume 1. I do not understand the proof, so i want someone to help me or to tell me a another book that have this proof more analytic. Thanks.

Comment: What is $ρ_ε$? And can you be more specific. You mention a ball. Do you restrict your function to a ball? How?

Comment: hi.$\rho_{\epsilon}$ is a mollifier.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Comment: Could you tell us what you don't understand in Bogachev's proof?